# How can I sort out a list of numbers according to certain characters in the middle of these numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, google-docs

So, at my job, we want to divide the work of checking certain items according to their registered numbers. Here's an example of these numbers:

0022499-80.2017

0200781-98.2016

0021322-13.2016

Items that end in **odd-odd** numbers before the dash, from right to left, should be checked by group A. Items ended in **odd-even** numbers should be checked by group B. Items ended in an **even** number belong to group C. So, the list above should be like this:

00224**99**-80.2017  -> A

02007**81**-98.2016  -> B

002132**2**-13.2016  -> C

How can I make a filter, preferably on libreoffice calc or Google docs, to make sorting easier?

Comment: From right to left. From the opposite direction, it should be odd-odd=A, even-odd=B, even=C.

Answer (score 1):

With `0022499-80.2017` in A2, put this in an unused column to the right and fill down.

```
=CHAR(ISEVEN(--MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2,1))+ISEVEN(--MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1,1))+65)
```

Comment: Could you expand a little? Libreoffice gives out a 501 error message.

Comment: Sounds like you should translate from excel to libre office. If you are unable or unwilling to do that, I'd humbly suggest you remove the microsoft-excel tag you applied to the question and specifically specify which platform you are trying to work under in your question.

Comment: Ok, I didn't try it on excel.

Comment: It looks like the original question did request a solution specifically for LibreOffice, although the tags included MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is @Jeeped's answer translated for LibreOffice:

```
=CHAR(ISEVEN(VALUE(MID(A2;FIND("-";A2)-2;1)))+ISEVEN(VALUE(MID(A2;FIND("-";A2)-1;1)))+65)
```

Notes on translation:

- Commas `,` may work in LibreOffice depending on locale, but semicolons `;` are recommended because they work no matter what the locale.
- `ISEVEN` requires a numeric argument, so `VALUE` converts to a number. Perhaps that is what `--` does in Excel? If so, that syntax seems strange to me.